Cannot remove the digit grouping symbol for number and currency in region - additional settings
After an issue with my motherboard I recently had to reinstall windows 10 on my pc (which is not capable of running windows 11 according to MS).
But since then the number and currency are not as I want them to be. (The look and feel I want are basically the same for number and currency so I only show it for number)
I like that a number is displayed like 1000.00 (and -1000.00 in red for negative numbers). (Only difference for currency is the currency symbol)
But all I can do via regional settings is make it like 1.000.00. If I try to remove that fricking digit grouping symbol via regional settings I get an error message telling me that it is not allowed to leave that symbol empty:
One or more of your regional settings are invalid. To fix this problem review and correct the customizable settings

I tried different regions (my native Dutch region and English World) but it keeps giving this issue. So either I select the wrong region or it is something else.
Note: I did find a hack which "solves" the issue by editing in regedit and set the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel'\International\sThousands and sMonThousands symbols to nothing. But then when I open the "additional settings" in the region dialog I keep getting that annoying popup telling me that the setting is invalid. And I don't like hacks like this.
How do I do this correct way? Can anybody help me?
Note: before the motherboard crash I had it working using the region settings (so not the hack), I just can't remember what I did at that time (5 years back or so) and in this case google is not my friend, so now I hope superuser is ;)
